# Can't get jquery on click code to work

Tags: jquery, audio

I'm having a problem with a piece of code which plays a short mp3/ogg file when a font awesome volume icon is clicked. The html works OK. The problem is with the js code

```
<p id="pathVar">/templates/beez_20/audio/dialogs/buy_flowers/</p>
<div id="dialog">
      <div id="title_block">Buying flowers </div>
    <div id="dlg_container">
    <div id="audio_player" >{audio}Buying flowers|dialogs/buying_flowers/buying_flowers.mp3{/audio}</div>
        <p class="dlg_content eng_dlg"><span class="dlg_text" id="bf01">Shopkeeper:     Good afternoon, how can  I help you?</span>&#xa0;<span class ="fa fa-volume-up fa-volume-up-dlg"></span> </p>
        <p class="dlg_content eng_dlg"><span class="dlg_text">สวัสดีตอนบ่าย,มีอะไรให้ฉันช่วยไหม?</span></p>
         ...
</div></div>
```

js code

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
jQuery("div#dlg_container").on("click",function (evnt) {
      var elementId = evnt.target.id,
        pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML,
        oggVar = pathVar+elementId+".ogg",
        mp3Var = pathVar+elementId+".mp3",
        audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
      audioElement.src = Modernizr.audio.ogg ? oggVar : mp3Var;
      audioElement.load();
      audioElement.play();
  });
});
```

Firebug shows that the elementId variable is nil, whereas it should contain, in example above, "bf01". I can't see why this is the case as similar code elsewhere works. I guess I'm missing something obvious here.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be that the actual element where the click originated may not have an id. So assuming all the `span.dlg_text` elements has an id and you want to be able to click anywhere in an `p.dlg_content` element try

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#dlg_container").on("click", 'p.dlg_content', function (evnt) {
        var elementId = $(this).find('.dlg_text').attr('id'),
            pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML,
            oggVar = pathVar + elementId + ".ogg",
            mp3Var = pathVar + elementId + ".mp3",
            audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
        audioElement.src = Modernizr.audio.ogg ? oggVar : mp3Var;
        audioElement.load();
        audioElement.play();
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your code (it works well) and your explanation. I wasn't really aware of the second "on" parameter and how it worked. very helpful. A good learning experience. Cheers

Comment: to Arun P Johny, I tried to identify my comment as directed to you but SO stripped out the "at" symbol and name. Nevermind, thanks

Comment: @RoyS The model of event registration is called [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) which is normally used when you want to register handlers for dynamically added elements

Answer (score 0):

You are attaching a click event to a parent container, which has many divs with id attribute. So as per your example, if you click on 
**{audio}Buying flowers|dialogs/buying_flowers/buying_flowers.mp3{/audio** elementID will be **audio_player**

Similarly if you click on **>Shopkeeper:     Good afternoon, how can  I help you?** elementID  will be **bf01**

So if you want to attach you click event to "bf01" just attach click event to that specific div.

```
jQuery("#bf01").on("click",function (evnt) {
      var elementId = evnt.target.id,
        pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML,
        oggVar = pathVar+elementId+".ogg",
        mp3Var = pathVar+elementId+".mp3",
        audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
      audioElement.src = Modernizr.audio.ogg ? oggVar : mp3Var;
      audioElement.load();
      audioElement.play();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Also possible to add onClick() event to the html element so it fires a javascript function:

**HTML**

```
<div id="dlg_container" onClick="play_sound('some_defined_event')"></div>
```

**JS function:**

```
function play_sound(evnt) {
    var elementId = evnt.target.id,
    pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML,
    oggVar = pathVar+elementId+".ogg",
    mp3Var = pathVar+elementId+".mp3",
    audioElement = document.createElement("audio");
    audioElement.src = Modernizr.audio.ogg ? oggVar : mp3Var;
    audioElement.load();
    audioElement.play();
};
```

Related: [onclick Event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)